# Microsoft Teams API

Tags: api, microsoft-teams, graph-api

I have requirements where using Team API I have to perform following tasks

1. Identify if teams have any files or folders inside it
2. Get the Teams permission
3. Conversation, Teams have any private or public channels
4. If my team integrate with any PowerBI or chatbot

Please share any supporting articles or API information

Comment: Have you checked the Microsoft docs?

Comment: Yes, I found the following API https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/channel?view=graph-rest-1.0
Now working on how to use that